# Highlight item in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I want to render a couple of elements using an `ItemsControl`, and highlight one of them

My ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Item> Items;
    public Item HighlightedItem;
}
```

My XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <myUserControl Background="{?}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I want to highlight the item by setting the background property to something specific, how should I go on about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First have a converter which will compare reference of two objects say `ObjectEqualsConverter`

```
public class ObjectEqualsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter        

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values[0] == values[1];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, 
                                CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } 
    #endregion
}
```

And in `XAML` file, use converter to check if `current item is same as highlighted item in ViewModel` and in case converter returns true set the `color` of control using `trigger`-

```
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <myUserControl x:Name="myControl" />
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ObjectEqualsConverter}">
                                <Binding/>
                                <Binding Path="DataContext.HighlightedItem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <Setter TargetName="myControl" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Make sure you add converter as a `resource` in your xaml file.

Comment: Works for me! Thanks. Deserves Accept.